# Providing the Type to instanciate a generic Class

Tags: c#, generics

I got the following code to create my class :

```
public class GenericObject<T>
{
    [...]

    public GenericObject(object source, string propertyName)
    {
        [...]
    }
}
```

and then I'd like to create instances of my Class. here is the loop I have :

```
        foreach (PropertyInfo pi in container.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
                //var type = pi.PropertyType;
                GenericObject<pi.PropertyType> p = new GenericObject<pi.PropertyType>(container, pi.Name);
        }
```

The compiler tells me that 'pi' is not a namespace (???)
I tried with this code :

```
Type type = pi.PropertyType;
GenericObject<type> p = new GenericObject<type>(container, pi.Name);
```

but I got the same error ('type' not a namespace)
What have I to do ? thx in advance for any help

Comment: It's not very clear from your code (what is `PrimitivePropertyProxy` for example and where are you using `GenericObject`), but the problem you have is that `pi.PropertyType` is a **variable**, not a **type**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is that `pi.PropertyType` is a **variable** that contains a class that represents a type, not a **type** its self.

Generics expect a type, not a variable. You could dynamically create the type as per Jakub's answer, although i'm not sure that's what you want or need.

---

To be honest i'm not sure how much better your generic class is than just having one that holds `object`s. Since you're going to be creating this generic class with reflection, you're not going to get the type-safety you'd typically use generics for.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot create a dynamic type at the runtime by passing a variable to `<>`.

You need to call **[MakeGenericType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype.aspx)** and provide your generic types there.

Here's an example

```
Type d1 = typeof(List<>);    
Type[] typeArgs = { typeof(string) };    
Type makeme = d1.MakeGenericType(typeArgs);

object o = Activator.CreateInstance(makeme);    
List<string> itsMe = o as List<string>;    
Console.WriteLine((itsMe == null) ? "Failed" : "Succeeded");
```

Comment: I don't understand why dyou have 2 types to call on MakeGenericType. In my example, "pi.PropertyType" can only be of Type Int32, String, Boolean and Double, but what abut the 2nd type use ? (the List one)

Comment: I think I get it, but I still don't know how to use it in my line : GenericObject<???> p = new GenericObject<???>(container, pi.Name);
What should I put in "???" ?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case that someone got exactly the same problem one day, here is the solution :

```
        foreach (PropertyInfo pi in container.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
                Type generic = typeof(GenericObject<>);
                Type[] typeArgs = { pi.PropertyType};
                Type constructed = generic.MakeGenericType(typeArgs);
                object[] args = new object[] { container, pi.Name };
                var p = Activator.CreateInstance(constructed, args);
        }
```

We could "approximatively" say that this it the equivalent of what I wanted :

```
GenericObject<pi.PropertyType> p = new GenericObject<pi.PropertyType>(container, pi.Name);
```

(so to speak)